# EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent fires constantly in Android Studio Logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, egl

I have Googled `EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent` looking for a solution to why this keeps popping up - but nothing that I can find that really matches what I am doing. There are a couple of unanswered SO questions that touch this subject. But again, I am still unsure what is causing it. I am building a Kotlin application.

I don't want to just regex it out -- **if there is an actual issue I want to resolve it.**

My app can be doing nothing. I can clear the log and in just a few seconds I have hundreds of these events.

But while my app is running this is just a constant stream and it makes it incredibly difficult to find my own log output.

***How do I resolve this issue?*** I don't even know what would be causing it to post any code.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm a bit late but I found these answers in another SO question.

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70376084/why-am-i-seeing-egl-emulation-app-time-stats-in-the-log-when-running-on-an-andro) there are two answers, from 2022 and 2023 respectively, that could solve this problem.

In short:
[image: Right-click Logcat line to show options]

Right click `EGL_emulation` and choose between `Fold Line Like This` and `Ignore Tag "EGLemulation"`. This works with AS Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2

You can find [Answer one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73923601/14120486) and [answer two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76336137/14120486) here

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer instead of linking to other questions

Comment: Updated @NicoHaase