# Why am I seeing EGL_emulation app_time_stats in the log when running on an Android 12 emulator?

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, logcat, android-12

When testing a Flutter app on an emulator running Android 12, I'm seeing lines like these in the logs at regular intervals (approximately every second):

```
D/EGL_emulation(32175): app_time_stats: avg=312.93ms min=133.69ms max=608.57ms count=4
```

What do they mean, and how do I turn them off? I've never seen them on Android 11 emulators, so I'm guessing it has something to do with Android 12?

Comment: Any solutions to this? I tried using Android 12 on my new Apple Silicon Mac, and I ma seeing these too.

Comment: Did you solve this? I see this since the update now in my `RUN` console window, so the other answers suggesting to edit the `LogCat` window don't really apply unfortunately

Comment: Anyone has a clue what is the meaning of these logs?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just click on this line then it will be filtered

[image]

Answer (score 73):

- Right click on `D/EGL_emulation ...` in your RUN console window
- Click "Fold Lines Like This"
- Edit the filter that's just been added to only contain `D/EGL_emulation`.
- All these lines will be removed from the RUN console window now

Comment: the only valid answer for Run window

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Where are these fold expressions saved now? If I want to clear them how to?

Comment: 2023 not working

Comment: This is not a real solution, because it depends on a functionality of the IDE which is sometimes not given, i.e. when using Neovim.

Answer (score 20):

All these EGL_emulation messages are very annoying, indeed. My solution so far is to create a custom logcat filter.

You can open the logcat filter configuration by clicking on the drop-down far right of the logcat-toolbar and select *Edit Filter Configuration*. You have to set two regular expressions:

- `^(?!(EGL_emulation))` in the *Log Tag* field filters all messages with the "EGL_emulation" tag.
- `^(?!(\?))` in the *Package Name* field filters all messages from apps without debug information. This is not as good as the *Show only selected application* filter, [but the closest thing to a similar behavior so far](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66133894/398844).

Here is also a screenshot of my config, just in case the text is unclear:

[image: Logcat filter]

However, I really hope this problem is fixed upstream as soon as possible ;)

Comment: This answer works, but the fact that it is a filter that you have to use instead of "show only selected application" and you have to manage it yourself now - its not great. The annoyance of using @Jammo's answer and still getting "XX internal lines" at the end of every other log message - is still better.

Comment: Thanks for this, driving me crazy as well.  Android studio & XCode both feel like relics from 1999 vs a modern terminal+vscode workflow.

I've looked really hard but can't find the drop-down.  There's one by the top logcat tabs but it only has Show Toolbar, View mode, etc.  There's a - button next to it that minimzes the toolbar. Below that I can favorite my quick filters, but again no configuration is available...

Answer (score 17):

These are messages from the Android emulator and can be helpful in some situations. I would suggest ***only filtering out the Debug messages***, and not the Warning or Error messages as those may be useful.

Prefix:

- `D/` - Debug
- `W/` - Warning
- `E/` - Error

**For Android Studio Logcat logs**:

- Use the method recommended [in Torben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71071810/16593914) in logcat but modify to `^(?!(D/EGL_emulation))` so that Warnings and Errors will still show.

**For VSCode Debug Console logs**:

- Simply use a Filter exclusion string as `!D/EGL_emulation`.

Comment: At least on Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 it seems like the prefixes are not part of the tag/message, so i could not include them to the regex

Comment: Same, this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

In Android Studio Electric Eel add `-tag:EGL_emulation` in the filter line like this:

[image: filter line]

Answer (score 11):

In VSCode, with the debug console tab open, go to the filter (bottom right side) and set the following: `!D/EGL_emulation`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On the newer Android Studio[Giraffe], now you can right-click on the line and select "Ignore Tag  " which will hide it from the logcat.

[image]

Comment: How do you undo ignoring a tag this way?  Where can I configure or reset those ignored tags?

Comment: I found where: Android Studio > Settings... > Tools > Logcat > Ignore tags.

Answer (score 0):

I was having difficult understanding how to use the new LogCat and filters in Electric Eel and here is how I got rid of the EGL_Emulation lines:

I needed tags with Crypton or (|) MainActivity | package:mine and (&) not (!) egl_emulation:

`tag:Crypton | tag:MainActivity | package:mine  & !EGL_emulation`

This works great and shows you how to have multiple tags and how to use logical conditions.

Here's what it looks like in AndroidStudio
[image: AndroidStudio logcat filter]

Answer (score -1):

This is showing how many times your screen is rebuilding.