# A RenderFlex overflowed by 5.9 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

a strange loop of this is printed when I Change something on Textfield.
and I call `onchanged` property?
please take a look at my simple training project and give me a hint why is that.

```
/EGL_emulation(16364): app_time_stats: avg=87.47ms min=7.45ms max=509.56ms count=16
D/EGL_emulation(16364): app_time_stats: avg=499.63ms min=497.86ms max=501.87ms count=3
D/EGL_emulation(16364): app_time_stats: avg=499.17ms min=497.93ms max=500.98ms count=3
D/EGL_emulation(16364): app_time_stats: avg=501.99ms min=501.19ms max=502.79ms count=2
D/EGL_emulation(16364): app_time_stats: avg=498.45ms min=497.55ms max=499.96ms count=3
D/EGL_emulation(16364): app_time_stats: avg=500.55ms min=499.10ms max=502.01ms count=2
D/EGL_emulation(16364): app_time_stats: avg=500.25ms min=498.48ms max=502.46ms count=3
Application finished.---------
```

here is the code

Comment: The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#51f83 relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share the code you have tried..

Comment: This console output is harmless and has probably nothing to do with the overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70376084/why-am-i-seeing-egl-emulation-app-time-stats-in-the-log-when-running-on-an-andro

Comment: Where is the code?